# “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)” OSX XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

Xdebug (2.4.0) is not working on NetBeans (8.2) on OSX (10.13.2) using XAMPP (7.0.26-0).

I've just installed all these and just trying out test file, but it shows

> “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)”

No break points work.

I have these code on php.ini, there is no Additional .ini files parsed

```
zend_extension = "/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.26_18/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.9
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

xdebug support => enabled shows when I run php -i on command line.
I read many other thread but no luck so far. Anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: 1) If you are trying to debug a web page .. then better check `phpinfo()` output captured in a same way (via browser) -- just in case more than one PHP/php.ini is used by CLI and Apache. 2) Double verify your IP -- `127.0.0.1` might be enough (if it all runs on the same computer/OS -- no VM/remote of any kind) 3) Check what xdebug log has to say about it -- at least it can tell if it tries to connect and what the response is.

Comment: Thank you! I found 
`Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)`
on bash (php -i), but there is `Scan this dir for additional .ini files: (none)`one on browser. php info() on browser has no Xdebug. Do you know what do I need to do?  I don't see conf.d file or directory.

Comment: As long as `Additional .ini files parsed` shows `(none)` -- it does not matter as it means that even if it was looking for a files it did not loaded any additional configs. Better check what `Loaded Configuration File` points to -- what php.ini was loaded etc. Your *"php info() on browser has no Xdebug."* clearly indicates that this might be the issue -- it loads different php.ini file.

Comment: Thank you for letting me understand that browser and bash look at different php (module?). I edited correct php.ini file that was on the path indicated on php info via browser, now works all fine. Thank you :)